# Entity Framework "Unexpected Connection State" Exception

Tags: c#, entity-framework, signalr

After three hours of debugging and searching, I'm hoping someone here has an answer. Entity Framework (using MySQL) throws the following exception if I call the following function quickly in succession (e.g. < 0.1 seconds apart).

> System.InvalidOperationException: Unexpected connection state. When using a wrapping provider ensure that the StateChange event is implemented on the wrapped DbConnection.

However, sometimes the function works without any problems. The exception is thrown on the first `ToList()` call:

```
void InsertOrUpdateMaterials(List<Material> materials)
{
    var id = GetUserId();
    var materialIds = materials.Select(x => x.MaterialId).ToList();

    // Remove old materials from DB
    var oldMaterials = Db.Materials.Where(p => p.CreatedBy == id && 
            materialIds.Contains(p.MaterialId)).ToList(); // exception
    Db.Materials.RemoveRange(oldMaterials);
    Db.SaveChanges();

    // Replace previous materials with the new ones in list
    Db.Materials.AddRange(materials);
    Db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Oddly, this error never occurred on the development server, so I looked into possible configuration issues to no avail.

Sometimes, Entity Framework throws:

> System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException: There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first.

Again pointing to the `ToList()` call. Any ideas?

Comment: It would be helpful to see where `Db` is coming from. My guess is that it really is telling the truth - between opening the initial connection on Db, and you executing `ToList`(you get the exception here because this is when the query is "materialised" against the database) the state of the connection has changed (closed, etc). EF is hinting that you should be handling `StateChange` to handle this (e.g reopen connection or whatever)

Comment: Your comment helped me find the solution! Thank you, sir!! I looked at where `Db` was coming from, and the context was being cached. I made it initialize a new context each time and the problem resolved. Really surprising how I let that one slip.

Comment: @arao6 care to write a more detailed answer? FYI you can write an answer to your own question in StackOverflow. And, FWIW, I will probably upvote it :)

Comment: Please someone write a more detailed answer.

Comment: Make sure you create a new DB context when you use it with `using (var db = new DbContext()) { ...  use it ...}`.

Answer (score 5):

For other people that might a similar problem. Based on the above comments it seems that the code uses a cached db-context. After the db-context was created the db-connection broke (no `StateChange`handler was installed in the application). After the connection breakdown the application used the cached db-context to perform some operations on it.

Creating a new db-context solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with `Effort.EF6` 1.3.0. The fix for me was to update the `NMemory` dependency from 1.1.0 to 1.1.2.

Comment: are you seeing the same parallelization issue as https://stackoverflow.com/a/47862865 ?

Comment: I'm not sure, I'm using NUnit 3.7.  I fixed my problem changing the way my DbContext was handled as @Stephen Byrne suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem using `Effort.EF6`, but updating `NMemory` (as [user326608](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47278132/1802740) suggested) didn't help. Turns out [XUnit is executing tests in parallel by default since V2](https://xunit.github.io/docs/capturing-output.html).

Disabling this behavior fixed it for me. Add the following to AssemblyInfo.cs:

```
using Xunit;
[assembly: CollectionBehavior(CollectionBehavior.CollectionPerAssembly)]
```

Although I see this as a workaround, as unit tests should be independent from each other.

Comment: Why are you using real database in unit tests.   Mock it out so it is faster.

Answer (score 0):

Please be careful that you don't use DbContext in other thread, only use it in the UI thread.
If you need to call function that including DbContext from other thread,
you need to call it via the `SynchronizationContext` class.

I think the DbContext cannot be used at the same time each thread UI and others.