# Unexpected connection state when multiple requests at the same time

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, entity-framework-6, asp.net-core

We use ASP.NET Core and EF6 for database requests.
Potentially, multiple user can access at the same time at the database. I materialized the situation with a unit test :

```
Parallel.For(0, 10, count => {
    result = userRepo.Sessions.Any(session => session.Token == token);
});
```

An exception is thrown : `Unexpected connection state. When using a wrapping provider ensure that the StateChange event is implemented on the wrapped DbConnection`.

This is something I completly understand : the code is trying to access to the database with the same connection in parallel, but the connection is closed before one request has finished. Ok, but with ASP.NET Core and Dependency Injection, the same connection can be shared between 2 requested, and so it can potentially crash like the test above. We use `AddScoped` for the registration of database services in DI container.

I there something I'm missing in our architecture ?

Comment: typically dbcontext will be scoped per request and each request will have its own connection, which goes out of scope and is disposed at the end of the request.

Comment: Two requests **can't** use the same connection, because they are scoped (by default). Scoped will create one instance of DbContext per request. What you are trying is not how ASP.NET Core requests would work. You will have to instantiate a new user repository and a new context for each iteration of your loop. Read: your unit test is just plain wrong ;)

Comment: If multiple HTTP requests are using the same instance of `DbContext`, you did it wrong.  This unit test is testing a scenario that shouldn't happen.

Comment: Thanks guys, we simplified our architecture and the problem has gone. We suspect another connection to the database in our middleware which was causing the issue.

Comment: Sorry for my mistake, the problem did not gone, but we saw that the error only appear with Chrome and the pre-rendering that the browser performs when the user begin to type the URL

Comment: After some investigations, we passed our `DbContext` into the DI with AddTransient and not AddScoped, and it solved the problem. Very odd, it's seems that EF6 or the MySQL connector (?!) keep existing connections and affect one existing connection to the new `DbContext`, is that possible ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Entity Framework "Unexpected Connection State" Exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28653352/entity-framework-unexpected-connection-state-exception)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of investigations, we found the problem. We cached entire C# lambda expressions, which access to the database through Entity Framework, so from one HTTP request to another, the `DbContext` was the same, that's why this exception was thrown.